# Azure Container Jobs - No logs, Execution failed

Tags: azure, containers

Azure Container Jobs - With manual triggering. My jobs always failed, but in logs there is nothing.

In Container App Enviroment logs is:
`"Msg":"Container \u0027acjob3\u0027 was terminated with exit code \u0027139\u0027 and reason \u0027ProcessExited\u0027","Reason":"ContainerTerminated","EventSource":"ContainerAppController","Count":1`

In logs there are tables **ContainerAppSystemLogs_CL** and **ContainerAppSystemLogs_CL**, (on screenshot below), but both contains same logs without any information..
[Screenshot with logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBJzg.png)

Is there any way how to get why it failed?

To see error which cause termination of container or any console logs from container itself

Answer (score 0):

Here I have created a container registry and pushed a image into my repositories (ACR).

[image]

Then, By Specify the image from the container registry created a new Container Job in the portal.

[image]

- Trigger the Azure Container Job manually from the Azure portal. After the job fails, navigate to the Azure Container App Environment logs. Look for entries indicating the termination of the container with exit code 139.

I have navigated to the container job logs to check if there are any details about the termination reason or additional logs.

- I have the access to the host machine to review system logs. Firstly, you should configuration verbose logging in the application.

[image]